# Grape swagger documentation not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swagger, swagger-ui, grape-api

Below is the configuration I used to build API's using `Grape`.

But I am not able to build documentation using `Swagger`

Gems:

```
gem 'grape'
grape-0.13.0
gem 'grape-swagger-rails'
grape-swagger-rails-0.1.0
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
rack-cors-0.4.0
```

config/application.rb

```
require 'rack/cors'
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb') 
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '**', '*.rb')]
```

config/initializers/swagger.rb

```
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.url      = '/swagger_doc.json'
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.app_url  = "http://api.lvh.me:3000"
```

config/routes.rb

```
  constraints(subdomain: 'api') do
    mount API::Base => '/'
  end
  mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine, at: "/apidocs"
```

app/api/api/base.rb

```
require 'grape-swagger'
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
    default_format :json
    mount API::V1::Base

    add_swagger_documentation(
      api_version: "v1",
      hide_documentation_path: true,
      mount_path: "/",
      hide_format: true
    )
  end
end
```

**Issue:**

When I hit `http://lvh.me:3000/apidocs`. I'm getting below error below green Nav bar.

> Can't read swagger JSON from http://api.lvh.me:3000/swagger_doc.json

When I hit `http://api.lvh.me:3000/swagger_doc.json`. Getting below response.

```
{"error":"Not Found"}
```

I am not able to figure out what am doing wrong. Need help in rendering Swagger documentation with grape framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/initializers/swagger.rb` you set the URL to your schema to `/swagger_doc.json` and to `mount_path` in the method `add_swagger_documentation` you pass `'/'`. Shoudn't it be `/swagger_doc` ?

Comment: After removing swagger_doc from initializer and from mouth_path, all the apis I wrote got popped up. But it is not loading any information regarding api. I see some calls going to api with response as authorized because it should have Authorized header with api key which it is not having. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I removed mount_path and GrapeSwaggerRails.options.url  from initializer and it worked.

Comment: How can I change Base Url? From `http://api.lvh.me:3000/swagger_doc` to `http://api.lvh.me:3000/v1`

Comment: Put back `mount_path` in add_swagger_documentation and `options` in swagger.rb but this time with the **same** path, because if they are absent it defaults to 'swagger_doc'. After that mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine at "v1".